# Constraints in ASP.NET MVC route issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to create an example from [this website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

They've defined a route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
);
```

It works mean `The resource could not be found` error will occur when *productId* has no integer value. (I accessed http://website.com/product/1a  then error is displayed otherwise will display a view)

But if I change the url format from route into like this:

```
"Product/{action}/{productId}"
```

And access it like: http://website.com/Product/Details/1a , then an error is occurred like: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method`

So, why is not displayed the `The resource could not be found` error ? Why action is reached while I put a **constraint** to route ?

PS: I change the url format for route and now it looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{action}/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: What did you change exactly? How does the route look like?

Comment: See updated question. I already explained what I changed.

Comment: is that answer helpful to you i updated my answer why you got error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is not the route you specified but another route item in your code, most likely the default MVC route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When the value for `productId` doesn't match the constraint, the route engine moves on to check the next mapping. It then matches the last one, but when attempting to call your method, the model binder can't convert the string `1a` to an `int` which effectively means that the `productId` parameter is missing.

Comment: The id is optional (in the default route) and should not throw this exception if it's null. After all the id is provided and isn't missing..

Comment: Because `id` is optional, that is why this route would match.

Comment: I agree with you, the route would match. But the id is provided and not missing.

Comment: Exactly, that's why the error happens and comes from the controller action invoker rather than a 404.

Comment: So why are you saying the productId parameter is missing? That confused me ;-D

Comment: It's missing because the model binder can't convert `1a` into a non nullable int.

Comment: I see we mean the same but express it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Why error `The resource could not be found`  for

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
);
```

when url is `http://website.com/product/1a`

**Answer :** Your getting error because when you apply constrain on the route of url , if constrain doesnt match MVC just reject that request ..that is the only reason you are getting error of resource not found.

---

why error `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method` for

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{action}/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"}
);
```

when url `http://website.com/Product/Details/1a`

Answer : in this case no routconstrain is applied so `ModelBinder` try to match parameter using `DefaultValuProvider` if it fails to match value to the parameter than it throws error as you are getting here as no conversion means null.

To avoid this error you can try this

a. pass defualt value to action method

```
  public ActionResult Index(int id=0)
```

b. create method with nullable parameter so null get handled automaticalyy

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? id)
```

---

Problem is not because of constrain route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
);
```

as per above code , you are looking for product id which is integer so if you provide string like `http://website.com/Product/Details/1a` it tries to match first value with first page holder means whatever after product matched with productId in this case...for matching this mvc use `ModuleBinder` when module binder finds its `string` not `int` i.e. not able to convert `string` in `int` it throws error you are getting.

**So for as per your route it matches `Details` with product id but not able to find match for `1a` that is the reason you are getting resource not found.**

---

When you have route like this `Product/{action}/{productId}`  and call url like this `http://website.com/Product/Details/1a`  it matches `Details` with `{action}` and `1a` with `{ProductId}` than you got error `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method`

Comment: That's the reason he is **not** getting the resource not found error ;)

Comment: For first example, I didn't access `http://website.com/Product/Details/1a` but `http://website.com/Product/1a`  as you see that Details is `missing` (that's why works)

Comment: @SnakeEyes - Check the answer that is the thing you might looking for